# Using (.) in case_when() as part of mutate() on grouped tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have the following kind of data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data <- tibble(a = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3),
               b = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z'),
               c = c('ps', 'ps', 'qs', 'rs', 'rs'),
               d = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500),
               strt = ymd(c('2019-03-20', '2020-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2020-05-01', '2016-01-01')),
               fnsh = ymd(c(NA, NA, NA, '2020-06-01', '2016-05-01')))
```

The operation has to apply to the data as grouped by a, b, c (i.e. `data %>% group_by(a, b, c)`).
I want to add a column that shows whether or not a group has a start within the latest year. To have a start within the latest year, a group has to:

1) Have a row with strt within the latest year

2) Not have a row with strt before the latest year and fnsh as NA (no disqualifying overlap)

3) Not have a row with strt before the latest year and fnsh as equal to or later than the latest of all entries in strt (no disqualifying overlap)

I am thus trying to get:

```
tibble(a = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3),
       b = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z'),
       c = c('ps', 'ps', 'qs', 'rs', 'rs'),
       d = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500),
       strt = ymd(c('2019-03-20', '2020-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2020-05-01', '2016-01-01')),
       fnsh = ymd(c(NA, NA, NA, '2020-06-01', '2016-05-01')),
       startLatestYear = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1))
```

My current approach is:

```
test <- data %>%
  group_by(a, b, c) %>%
  mutate(startLatestYear = case_when(all(is.na(fnsh)) &
                                     min(strt) > today(tzone = 'CET') - years(1) &
                                     min(strt) <= today(tzone = 'CET') ~ 1,
                                     strt > today(tzone = 'CET') - years(1) &
                                     strt <= today(tzone = 'CET') &
                                     nrow(filter(., strt < today(tzone = 'CET') - years(1) &
                                                    fnsh %in% NA)) == 0 &
                                     nrow(filter(., strt < today(tzone = 'CET') - years(1))) > 0 &
                                     strt > max(pull(filter(., strt < today(tzone = 'CET') - years(1)), fnsh)) ~ 1,
                                     TRUE ~ 0))
```

The first `if` in my use of `case_when()` seems to work, but the second does not. I suspect that my use of `.` is wrong. How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is a facility provided by the magrittr package, where it refers to the left-hand side of the `%>%` operator. `%>%` knows nothing about dplyr verbs, so when you use `.` inside the `mutate`, it simply expands to the object that was piped in. In the case of a grouped df, that means the *entire* df, not the grouped subsets.

The best solution I've found so far is to replace the `mutate` with a `group_modify`:

```r
data %>%
    group_by(a, b, c) %>%
    group_modify(function(.x, .y)
    {
        .x %>% mutate(startLatestYear=case_when(...))
    })
```

This works because now the pipeline inside `group_modify` is executed separately for each group.

Comment: @TimTeaFan `.y` represents the grouping levels of the passed-in object and is a required argument

Comment: @TimTeaFan the name is `group_modify` which means it's intended for use with grouped data. In this particular case the inner transformation doesn't make use of the grouping levels but in the general case that isn't true, so you need a way to pass them in

Comment: Note that the accepted answer gives us ```startLatestYear = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0)``` rather than ```startLatestYear = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1)``` as requested. The solution thus keeps more information than envisaged (with no down side).